# One site : multiple clients : how to organize

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I have a website (a tool) that I want to use for multiple clients. Ofcourse every client has separate logins, settings and content for his tool. So my question is: what is the smartest, safest, fastest way to organize this. I want this to be easy for the client and for myself.

**option A**: every client gets a subdomain and thus his own website + database. Disavantage:  when I perform an update on the code I have to edit every subdomain. Same for altering database-model. Advantages: ?

**option B**: one website that uses a global database for logins and a database per user. Once the user logs in, the website checks in the global database which client-database he needs and loads this one. Advantage: one site (= one update), separate databases (= safer?). Disadvantage: altering database-model means I have to update every database.

**option C**: one website that uses one database. All data from all clients gets stored in the same database. Advantage: one site (= one update), one database (= one update). Disavantages = database can get big? if database gets stolen, all data is in it and needs good programming to make sure client A only sees his stuff and not info from users B, C, etc.

option D?

I am programming in PHP and the database is MySQL.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Jeff

Comment: In general, you would store everything in one database.  However, you seem to understand the trade-offs of different solutions, so you have to decide on the requirements of the application.  Choose the solution that best matches those requirements.

Comment: This isn't an appropriate type of question for SO, or for any SE site. SE is for relatively narrow questions that can have specific answers, which can be judged correct/incorrect (you accept the most correct one). This is too broad, there are numerous possible approaches. It's more appropriate for site where you can have ongoing design discussion, not a question/answer site.

Comment: One downside of sharing the database is that each clients' activities will affect the other clients' performance. Depending on the nature of the business, some clients might not be too keen on the idea of their data intermingling with that of other clients.

Comment: Depending on your server and it's configuration one database can be totally fine for a long term. May we know what kind of tool you develop and how many clients you estimate to have? It would help alot helping you to find the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple subdomains does not necessitate multiple copies of the code.

Using subdomains is generally less safe, due to cookie scope issues.

I'd seriously consider dropping mysql as your db, and use postgres instead, as postgres is a database cluster, meaning it has multiple real databases on one server. mysql has only one database (but multiple schemas, called 'databases'). The advantage to this is that databases cannot communicate with each other but can be backed-up/restored independently.